# Using ReadLine input for a different method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program that, given my choice of variables, depicts a smiley on screen.

I've written the following.

Now my program asks three questions, which I will answer with numbers between 0 and 11. I would like to use these answers in the method 'tekenscherm'. How can I call these variables in that method?

```
class HalloForm : Form
{
    public string a,b,c = ""; //Declare them here.
    public HalloForm()
    {
        this.Text = "Hallo";
        this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
        this.Paint += this.tekenScherm;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Smiley size, on a scale of 1 tot 10?");
        string a = System.Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.Parse(a);
        System.Console.WriteLine("X coordinate of the smiley, on a scale of 1 to 10");
        string b = System.Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.Parse(b);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Y coordinate of the smiley, on a scale of 1 to 10");
        string c = System.Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.Parse(c);
        HalloForm scherm;
        scherm = new HalloForm();

        Application.Run(scherm);
    }
    void tekenScherm(object obj, PaintEventArgs pea)
    {

        SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        Pen blackBrush = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
        int x = 360;
        int y = x + 75;
        pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(blueBrush, 300, 200, 200, 200);
        pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, 300, 200, 200, 200);
        pea.Graphics.DrawArc(blackBrush, 350, 250, 100, 100, 45, 90);
        pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, a, 250, 5, 5); //I've used it here
        pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, y, 250, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good practice to name all variable/function names (in your case tekenScherm in English: drawScreen).

Comment: This is predominantly an English speaking website, if you want help it is recommended to write everything in English; the moment I see another language I just stop reading.

Answer (score 0):

Declare those variables outside of the method scope as integers.

`Int32.Parse` returns an integer value, which you are not assigning to those variables, so it's basically doing nothing the way you are using it.

Here is the working code:

```
class HalloForm : Form
{
    public int a, b, c = 0; //Declare them here.
    public HalloForm()
    {
        this.Text = "Hallo";
        this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
        this.Paint += this.tekenScherm;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Smiley size, on a scale of 1 tot 10?");
        a = Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        System.Console.WriteLine("X coordinate of the smiley, on a scale of 1 to 10");
        b = Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        System.Console.WriteLine("Y coordinate of the smiley, on a scale of 1 to 10");
        c = Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        HalloForm scherm;
        scherm = new HalloForm();

        Application.Run(scherm);
    }
    void tekenScherm(object obj, PaintEventArgs pea)
    {

        SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        Pen blackBrush = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
        int x = 360;
        int y = x + 75;
        pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(blueBrush, 300, 200, 200, 200);
        pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, 300, 200, 200, 200);
        pea.Graphics.DrawArc(blackBrush, 350, 250, 100, 100, 45, 90);
        pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, x, 250, 5, 5);
        pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, y, 250, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I use 'a' then in, for instance, the pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, a, 200, 200, 200); ?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to use them in any of the methods within that class.

Comment: I've edited my original post, using your code. But it doesn't work for me. Do I need to declare 'a' in the method tekenScherm?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've copy pasted your code. And it doesn't work at my computer because a, b, and c in the public static void Main() are giving errors. Also, in 'void tekenScherm' at the 'pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackBrush, a(!!!!!), 250, 5, 5)', it says that a is not defined. While I want it to be the integer that I assign it when the question "Smiley size, on scale of 1 to 10" is answered.